# are surjective etale morphisms between connected schemes finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f : X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective etale morphism with $X,Y$ both connected (maybe I need to assume noetherian?)

Must $f$ be finite?

If not, are there conditions can I impose on $X$ and $Y$ to ensure that $f$ is finite?

Comment: I don't think so, take for example the map $f:\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0,1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{A}^1\setminus\{0\}, z\mapsto z^2$ (in char $\neq$ 2). It is étale (restriction of an étale morphism), surjective, but not proper. But I don't know any condition to ensure that $f$ is finite.

Comment: Roland has actually said it, the only reasonable way to ensure that the map is finite is by properness. In that case, you do not need etale, just quasi-finite would do.

Comment: @Mohan I'm confused about what you're saying. Are you claiming that quasi-finite + surjective = finite?

Comment: Of course not. Proper and quasi-finite implies finite.

Comment: @Mohan And you should mention that  unramified implies locally quasi-finite.